# Why do I get a linking error after updating to Xcode 12?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine, linker

I have a Unity project that uses a native Swift + ObjC library that I made using Firebase MLKit. When trying to build for iOS, the Unity project always builds with Xcode 11.3.1, but when updating to any Xcode 12.X version, I get the following errors :

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMIDI'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers'
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers_$_NativeLibrary_iOS in NativeLibrary_iOS.a(NativeLibrary.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers_$_NativeLibrary_iOS in NativeLibrary_iOS.a(UIImage.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers_$_NativeLibrary_iOS)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreMIDI", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreMIDI_$_NativeLibrary_iOS in NativeLibrary_iOS.a(NativeLibrary.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreMIDI_$_NativeLibrary_iOS in NativeLibrary_iOS.a(UIImage.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreMIDI_$_NativeLibrary_iOS)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am not using either `swiftCoreMIDI` nor `swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers` in my code. For the record, I did recompile my native library with Xcode 12 before importing it again in Unity.

Things I have tried:

- Building a Unity project with a Swift library that doesn’t use Firebase MLKit : works fine
- Building an Xcode only project that uses Firebase MLKit : works fine
- Building the project with a more recent Unity version : fails
- Integrating the Firebase SDK frameworks directly instead of using CocoaPods : fails
- Adding an empty Swift file + bridging header to my project : fails
- Adding the user defined setting `LD_VERIFY_BITCODE = NO` in XCode : fails

I’m using:

- Xcode 12.2
- Firebase 6.34
- Swift 5.0
- Unity 2019.3.6f1

Any help would be appreciated, I’ve been stuck on this for a while!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I finally found the solution, it was linked to the *UnityFramework* target in Xcode. I had to remove some architectures that are not concerned by my build: `i386` and `x86_64`. In addition, I updated the *Library Search Paths* to include `$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift`.

To execute those actions automatically, you can add those lines in a `PostProcessBuild` file in your Unity project:

```
var projPath = pathToBuiltProject + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";
var proj = new PBXProject();
proj.ReadFromFile(projPath);

// Update the Library Search Paths of the whole Xcode project
proj.AddBuildProperty(proj.ProjectGuid(), "LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS", "$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift");

// Get the UnityFramework target and exclude the unwanted architectures
var unityFrameworkGuid = proj.TargetGuidByName("UnityFramework");
proj.SetBuildProperty(unityFrameworkGuid, "EXCLUDED_ARCHS", "i386");
proj.AddBuildProperty(unityFrameworkGuid, "EXCLUDED_ARCHS", "x86_64");
```